# Side by side divs w/ negative relative position

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create two side by side divs in a wrapper. The first div, #content, is a position:relative div.

```
#wrapper {
background-image: url(assets/images/BG2.gif);
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 996px;
overflow: auto;
}

#content {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
width: 745px;
background-color: red;
}

#important {
float: right;
position: relative;
top: -1120px;
width: 231px;
margin-right: 10px;
background-color: green;
}
```

The problem is that the second div, #important, is displayed under the first one. There is enough space for both divs and the padding/margins. I can make it work by floating it to the right and using a negative top position and it displays fine, but I feel as though there is a better/correct way of doing this.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <img src="assets/photos/bid day 046.jpg" alt="Bid Day" width="745" height="311" />
      <div id="fraternity">
      <p align="center"><span class="style5"><strong>TITLE</strong><br />
      Subtitle<br />
      Sub-subtitle</span></p>
      <p align="justify">depry derp</p>
      <p align="justify">derp derp derp</p>
      <p class="style5" align="center"><br/><strong>Title<br/>
      Twitter Feed</strong></p>   
      <div id="twitter">
        <script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
        <script>...</script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="something" data-width="292" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="false">
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div id="important">
    <p align="center"><strong>IMPORTANT INFORMATION</strong><br />Derp!</p>
    <img class="divider" src="assets/images/hr.gif" alt="HR" width="183" height="15" />
    <p align="center"><strong>Achievements<br /></p>
    <img class="divider" src="assets/images/hr.gif" alt="HR" width="183" height="15" />
    <p align="center" class="style11"><strong>UPCOMING  EVENTS<br /></strong>stuff<br /></p>
    <p align="center"><br /> <strong>more stuff</strong><br /></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post some html code too!

Comment: My bad. I'll post some for you to get a feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `#wrapper`s position be `relative` or `absolute`.

Then set the inner div positions to be `absolute`.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/kRHTj/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid absolute positioning, as I am converting this site from an old table layout design and I want the site to center in the page, regardless of what size screen one is on. Maybe I am misunderstanding your response as well as what I am doing.

Comment: @KyleHarvey I may have misread your original post.  Are you trying to get the two divs to position side-by-side?

Comment: Yes. I've got two divs in a wrapper. The wrapper has margins auto aligned. The two inner divs need to be side-by-side without using absolute positioning due to the centering of the wrapper. I know that relative positioning is relative to where the div originally shows, but is there a way to make something relative to a container div?

Comment: @KyleHarvey Just use the `float: left` property on the two divs and the container div.  That will get them to sit side by side.

Comment: I swear I tried that before. I tried floating left on both the divs and the container div and everything moved, but when I didn't float the container div, it all worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would float them both left or right.

Comment: I tried floating them before, and there was some reason I chose not too. I think someone suggested that floating them might cause problems with something somewhere...Either way, if I float them now, #important overlaps #content by about 10px, which seems to be what the newly appearing scrollbar takes up. If I change to overflow:hidden, #important disappears entirely (like my missing facebook feed...). Changing the width of #important doesn't make it reappear, so there shouldn't be a space issue.